# Pulling international street addresses / phone numbers from free-form text

Tags: regex, street-address

Hey, folks.  I'm looking for some regular expressions to help grab street addresses and phone numbers from free-form text (a la Gmail).

Given some text: `"John, I went to the store today, and it was awesome!  Did you hear that they moved to 500 Green St.?  ... Give me a call at +14252425424 when you get a chance."`

I'd like to be able to pull out:

`500 Green St.` (recognized as a street address)

`+14252425424` (recognized as a phone number)

What makes this problem easier is that I don't care about parsing text that gets pulled out.  That is, I don't care that `Green` is the name of the road or that `425` is the area code.  I just want to grab strings that "look like" addresses or telephone numbers.

Unfortunately, this needs to work internationally, as best as possible.

Anyone have any leads?  Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory: http://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone numbers as long as you have a list of all country codes and number formats is easy, street addresses I have no idea, the only advice I can give you is to validate each set of words @ addressdoctor.com

Answer (score 1):

You can give RecogniContact (-> [address-parser.com](http://address-parser.com)) a try, it recognizes both postal addresses and phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Chapter 7 of Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/regular_expressions/index.html). It touches both phone numbers and street addresses. I believe you can use this as a starting point. The international part seems tough. I suggest you build a first draft, try it on several locales, iterate and improve.

Comment: Ah, but I imagine this problem is already solved.  Do you know of any already-existing regular expressions that I may employ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can check http://regexlib.com/.  It's the #1 source of regex solutions for problems that shouldn't be solved with regexes. ;)

Comment: Alan, this looks like a great resource, thanks. Cursory search gave me several international phone number regexes; No international street address ones, though. I still believe this is hard.